# How to restore contacts in android from a .vcf file?

Tags: android, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

Hello `stackoverflow` I'm trying to develop an application that can backup and restore contacts, `backup` is no problem, but restoring is the problem, here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    Cursor cursor;
    ArrayList<String> vCard ;
    String vfile;
    FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = null;
    Button btnRestorects = null;
    Button btnBackupCts = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnRestorects = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRstCts);
        btnBackupCts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBackCts);

        vfile = "contacts.vcf";
        final String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/"+ vfile;

        final File f = new File(storage_path);

    btnBackupCts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (!f.exists())
                    f.createNewFile();
                mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storage_path, false);
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            getVcardString();
        }
    });

    btnRestorects.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            final Intent intent = new Intent();

            final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String tmptype = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("vcf");
            final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/contacts.vcf");

            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),tmptype);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private void getVcardString() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    vCard = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null&&cursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int i =0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
        {

            get(cursor);
            Log.d("TAG", "Contact "+(i+1)+"VcF String is"+vCard.get(i));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");
    }
    try 
    {
        mFileOutputStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void get(Cursor cursor)
{
    //cursor.moveToFirst();
    String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
    AssetFileDescriptor fd;
    try 
    {
        fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
        fis.read(buf);
        String vcardstring= new String(buf);
        vCard.add(vcardstring);


        mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());

    }
    catch (Exception e1) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

`Permissions`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I can restore in the above manner but the problem is when ever the code snippet is invoked I'm getting an alert dialog prompting to choose the application to open file, when I select `Contact` application it will work, but I want restore to happen automatically when we click the button Please help to learn, and help me in solving this riddle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be a great help if you can provide your whole code so that i can run and get the understanding of your issue

Comment: Please see the edited post for full source code @Meenal Sharma, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to restore the contacts

```
 final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
  String tmptype = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("vcf");
  final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/contacts.vcf");
  Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/x-vcard");
  startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks @Meenal Sharma but problem continues.

Comment: when i run it here on my device it just ask for the dialog where i wana store that contacts

Comment: what about while restore ?

Comment: i am talking about restore only,just replace your code of restore button with mine,and give it a try